# How can I add an external link to in blogger submenu where only blog data with lables is working?

Tags: html, hyperlink, blogger, submenu

```
<li itemprop='name'><a href='#' itemprop='name' target='_blank'/>Ex. Link</li>
```

It was like this before-

```
<li itemprop='name'><a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;search/label/Dokumentasi&quot;' itemprop='url'/>#</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

In a template of blogger, the following code is given in vertical dropdown menu to add links, OK.

```
<li itemprop='name'><a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl + &quot;search/label/categories&quot;' itemprop='url'>categories</a></li>
```

But, I want a to add a external link of any site, here, How can I add? Answer is below-

```
<li itemprop='name'><a expr:href='&quot;external-link.com&quot;' itemprop='url' target='_blank'>external-link</a></li>
```

Telling it in words- We have to add that ex. link between &quote; and  &quote;

And, look it is working.